# Moving a row from one sheet to another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Ok I am completely new to all of this so understand I know nothing.

I am working in google spreadsheet and I want when I mark a job Done in column I it moves the row to another spreadsheet. I have to sheets set up just don’t know how to make work.

I don’t know what script to use or how to import it the right way.

Can someone help?

I have tired a few script I found but get confused on where to put what information for it to work.

Comment: Hello! Could you send a sample of how is your sheet organized? What are the sheets' names?, Do you want to copy all the columns or just some?

Answer (score 0):

Move to Destination when marked done:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const jobdoneColumn = 1;
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "your sheet name" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == "Done") {
    let vs = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    let dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Destination Name");
    dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1,vs.length,vs[0].length ).setValues(vs);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this script for my project, but it moves 2 rows. What I have to change to move only one row? Regards

Comment: I tested it and it moves only one row.  I don't know what you are doing wrong but it works for me

Comment: The is an onEdit function so running via script editor or by menu is not possible unless you provide the event object via an intermediate function